# Funds stuck in contract, no success in contacting owner

Tags: contract-invocation, dapps

A few months ago I sent a small amount of ETH for token purchase. The transaction went through on etherscan.io, but no tokens were generated. No response when contract creators were emailed.
Is there a way to 'cancel' the transaction? Here is the ABI:

> [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"removeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"isOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_numOwners","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_lastDay","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"resetSpentToday","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_spentToday","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"addOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_required","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_h","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"confirm","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newLimit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setDailyLimit","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[{"name":"_r","type":"bytes32"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"revoke","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newRequired","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeRequirement","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"hasConfirmed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"changeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_dailyLimit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_owners","type":"address[]"},{"name":"_required","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_daylimit","type":"uint256"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Confirmation","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Revoke","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newRequirement","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RequirementChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"SingleTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"MultiTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"initiator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ConfirmationNeeded","type":"event"}]

Comment: What's the TxHash?

Comment: This looks like a multi-sig wallet. There is no way to 'cancel' the transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cancel a transaction that's been confirmed - that's the whole point of a trustless blockchain network like Ethereum.